MicroPython v1.22.2 on Raspberry Pi Pico W with RP2040 MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_CONN_EOF error
My Pico Pi W is connected to wifi - confirmed, as I can access it remotely, I see it in the router, etc...
Using this as a resource and directly copy/pasting: https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/v1.22-release/examples/network/http_client_ssl.py
import socket
import ssl

# I connect to WiFi here

def main(use_stream=True):
    s = socket.socket()

    ai = socket.getaddrinfo("google.com", 443)
    print("Address infos:", ai)
    addr = ai[0][-1]

    print("Connect address:", addr)
    s.connect(addr)

    s = ssl.wrap_socket(s)
    print(s)

    if use_stream:
        # Both CPython and MicroPython SSLSocket objects support read() and
        # write() methods.
        s.write(b"GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
        print(s.read(4096))
    else:
        # MicroPython SSLSocket objects implement only stream interface, not
        # socket interface
        s.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
        print(s.recv(4096))

    s.close()


main()

Address infos: [(2, 1, 0, '', ('142.250.179.238', 443))]
Connect address: ('142.250.179.238', 443)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 64, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 47, in main
OSError: (-29312, 'MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_CONN_EOF')

# Line 47 =     s = ssl.wrap_socket(s)
# Line 64 =     main()

This feels like it should be something so simple
I've tried also using urequests as in r = urequests.get("https://google.com") which returns the same exception, with and without stream in the first example (write/read vs send/recv), and with a different server / endpoint.

When connecting to WiFi, the import had a gc.threshold(500) which appears to have been the issue. Increased to gc.threshold(5000) (and tested with gc.disable() for good measure) and requests are successful.
